# Creating a database backup from web application GUI

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there a way, I could `back up` / `create a database dump` from the browser gui? I need to create a database back up from my web-application itself.

Comment: If you are using phpMyadmin, you can do using export option

Comment: @SilverBullet Is there a way, I could do using my own code?

Comment: what code you are using?

Comment: @SilverBullet `Java` on the server side

Comment: http://javaknowledge.info/backup-restore-mysql-database-using-java-complete-solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Java.lang.Runtime.exec()` to execute mysqldump from your java application. See example below.

```
String backupCmd = “mysqldump -u “+dbUser+” -p”+dbPass+” “+dbName+” -r backup.sql”;

// Tun mysql backup
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(backupCmd);

process.waitFor();
int exitCode = exitValue();

 if(exitCode == 0){    
    System.out.println(“Successfully created mysql backup”);    
} else {    
    System.out.println(“Failed to create mysql backup”);    
}
```